# How to create new row from a middle of a row in the query, Microsoft SQL server management

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I would like to know how to create a new row under a row where there're no existing rows afterwards .

For example

```
1 details 
2 details1 details2
```

I'd like while my typing indicator is on the word details1 to create a new empty row (numbered 3) , thanks .

Comment: You cannot control how SSMS works if that is your goal. And you will find that SSMS is not a good tool for manipulating data in a table using the graphical tools it provides.

Comment: This is most certainly something for your presentation layer, not SSMS; which is just an IDE.

Comment: @SMor Thanks, I just want to confirm what do you mean by manipulating date?
If not SSMS what will you suggest?

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry but I don't understand you.

Comment: What bit didn't you understand, @Hotcoffee, there's not a lot to it, I am afraid.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the reply , I'm just very clueless so I'd like to know what's "presentation layer" and what do you mean by when you say it's for it (what's for what) ?

Comment: It's the layer of the application that *presents* the data to the end user, @Hotcoffee . it's literally what it says on the tin.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the clarification , I agree with what you have said it is indeed for me to move around in the presentation layer more easily  .

Comment: The way you create new rows is by using an insert statement.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm looking to insert rows in the presentation layer ( text editor )

Comment: Don't use the graphical data editor. It is awful and has bugs. Learn how to write an insert statement. It will be a little slower initially but once you learn sql statements you won't want to use the visual tools anymore.

Comment: @SeanLange I appreciate that .